# ClassCastException getting remote stub from JBoss 7 with JNLP

Tags: java, rmi, jnlp, classcastexception

I've wrote an adapter to get a remote interface of my bean from JBoss 7.

```
public DAdapter(Context context, boolean remote) throws DAdapterException {
    try {
        if (context==null){
            context = new InitialContext();
        }
        String res = "ear_name/jar_name/DAdapterBean!xxx.yyy.DAdapterRemote";
        dAdapter = (IDAdapter)context.lookup(res);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new DAdapterException("Could not create DmsAdapter service.", ex);
    }
}
```

DAdapterRemote is a remote interface, that extends IDAdapter. Its EJB3.
If I run this method from sandbox (from Eclipse), it works like a charm. But when I do it in my JNLP application context, I get ClassCastException.

```
context.lookup(res)
```

returns me sun.proxy.$Proxy in both cases and it has methods declared in IDAdapter.

I even tried reflections but it seems that argument classes versions are different from the ones, used in interface - at least it can't find appropriate methods by (methodName, args) method. I can swear they are the same.

What should I check first?

Comment: Very poor API design. You should either accept a Context parameter or declare and create your own as a local variable. Otherwise you have the complication of whether or not to close it, which you've overlooked completely, so at present you're leaking Contexts. I would get rid of the ability to accept null as a Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was solved. I had two differnt classloaders, and both of them had similar classes of my POJOs, so it brought me to X.class.equals(X.class) -> false and crushed my cast to interface, because methods had different signatures.